# Netbeans: COMMIT [HEAD] does not exist

Tags: git, netbeans

Using Netbeans (I just updated to v7.4 and I'm still having the problem), I have cloned a projet from a GIT repository. After it, when I do commit and push, everything is working fine. However, since Commit/Push via Netbeans can be very slow with big projects, sometime to save time, I do commit and puch directly from the command line. Here are the commands I'm using to commit/push manually:

```
git add -Av
git commit -avm "commit via command line"
git push -v origin
```

It works just fine. The only problem is that after it, it looks that Netbeans does not regognize my git project anymore. For example, if I change a file, the tab does not become blue anymore. Also, if I try to do a Commit via Netbeans, I'm receiving the following error

```
COMMIT [HEAD] does not exist
```

So, is it a bug with Netbeans?
Is there a way to manually reset/fix the Netbeans project so that it works fine with git even when I do git command via the command prompt? The only work arround I found is to do a new complete Clone of the project in a new blank folder via Netbeans.

Thanks in advance for any help somebody could provide me about this behaviour.

G. Plante

Answer (score 10):

Purely using the Netbeans (V8) Git facility I initialised a local repository from my new Netbeans project and as you say when I tried to commit I received the COMMIT [HEAD] does not exist error.  Simply by stopping and starting Netbeans the commit then worked.  So if in doubt reboot !

Comment: Awesome! It is helpful.